# Reference request for additive persistence of a number

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, textbook-recommendation

It is well known fact that each natural number can be represented uniquely in any base. So we can define digit sum function whose value is sum of digits of the natural number in given base.

Let $f(n,b)$ be digit sum of n in base b. It is very easy to prove that for each n in natural number there exist a k such that $f^k(n,b)$ [function composition] is a digit in base $b$. The smallest such $k$ is called additive persistence of $n$.

Where I can find the research articles published on these topics? I am able to only find few articles in ResearchGate and a few other websites. Can you give references where this additive persistence is used or its properties are discussed?

Comment: Some references are given at http://oeis.org/A006050

Comment: Did that help any?

Comment: Thanks for that , but the all references were listed on that site were available in other websites also except this -  H. J. Hinden, The additive persistence of a number, J. Rec. Math., 7 (No. 2, 1974), 134-135. I am not getting how to access this article also.

Comment: A library should be able to get it for you on interlibrary loan.

Comment: Due to Covid- 19 no Universities / libraries opened in my country so I was exploring any other way to get them and Thank you for your suggestion.